# Testing react hook that expects event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks-testing-library

I am writing a hooks library and want to write unit tests using [react-hooks-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library).  I have a hook for helping with form state "use-form" that's just a wrapper around the recommended  pattern for updating from form state from the React docs:

```
const useForm = initialState => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const handleChange = (eventOrValue, fieldName) => {
    if (eventOrValue.nativeEvent && eventOrValue.nativeEvent instanceof Event) {
      // if a react synthetic event...
      setState({
        ...state,
        [eventOrValue.target.name]:
          eventOrValue.target.type === 'checkbox'
            ? eventOrValue.target.checked
            : eventOrValue.target.value
      });
    } 
  return [state, handleChange];
};
```

My test so far -

```
  test('should update state on change', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() =>
      useForm({
        foo: 'bar'
      })
    );
    const [draft, handleChange] = result.current;

    //handleChange(new Event????)

    expect(draft.foo).toBe('xxx');
  });
```

How do I pass an event to the hook's handleChange function?